# Unable to send FCM Message using Cloud Functions for Firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-functions

I  am trying to send a basic use-case of sending FCM message using Cloud Functions for Firebase. The function is timing out and the message never got send. Here is the function.

```
exports.sendNotification = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    const keyword = req.query.keyword;
    const username = req.query.username;

    var payload = {
        data: {
            SearchKeyword: keyword,
            user: username
        }
    };

    const token = "real_fcm_token";

    return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(token, payload);


});
```

How can I update the above code block to be able to send a data message to a device?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to returning the `Promise` from `sendToDevice()`, you must also [send HTTP status](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events#terminate_http_functions).  For example:

```
res.status(200).send('Success');

const token = "real_fcm_token";

return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(token, payload);
```

Comment: Thanks, that solved the issue of time out, but for some reason, the FCM message is still not being sent.

Comment: @ValOkafor:  `sendToDevice()` returns a [MessagingDevicesResponse](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.messaging.MessagingDevicesResponse) in the promise.  You can get success/failure status from it:  [example code here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/admin/send-messages#send_to_individual_devices).